# border-radius disables YouTube Embed on FF

Tags: firefox, iframe, youtube, embed

On this site http://drehmomentproduktion.ch/showreel I use videos from Vimeo and YouTube along with some border-radius stylings appended to the iFrames.

Now the strange thing is if I view it in FF (8.0.1) the YouTube Videos are just black squares.
In all other browsers they work well.

If I disable `border-radius` the YouTube videos are looking fine.

How is that possible to disable embedded videos with `border-radius`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. Use this iFrame code. The `wmode=transparent`attribute is important!

```
<iframe width="464" height="261" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""
     src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/rZ2dIVB1vmk?wmode=transparent&amp;autohide=1&amp;egm=0&amp;hd=1&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;showsearch=0"></iframe>
```